# Is it possible to have a Modal div that isnt a dialog and is inline block with the rest of the page?

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

Most people use Modal within a Dialog (it appears in front of the rest of the page). Is it possible to have a div that appears via slideToggle() and is then modal but still inline with the rest of the page?

This shows the general idea

http://jsfiddle.net/55wwaw05/1/

When you click the red button it slideToggles a div which should be modal, only the blue button should be clickable and when it is clicked the modal div disappears.

```
ignore this
$('#btn').click(function() {
$('#first').slideToggle(100);
$('#second').css("background-color","grey");
$('#btn').attr("disabled", true);
```

Comment: Set the div on top of clear overlay that covers page. Overlay will prevent other elements being clicked

Answer (score 0):

Use the modal with one of the inline-block classes that matches the desired screen size:

- .visible-xs-inline-block
- .visible-sm-inline-block
- .visible-md-inline-block
- .visible-lg-inline-block

**References**

- [Bootstrap 3: Responsive Utilities](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#responsive-utilities)